# Manage SQL Agent Jobs On Multiple Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to deploy/modify/remove//manage SQL Agent Jobs across multiple servers within a domain without third-party software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Go to View -> Registered Servers.

Go into Database Engine -> Local Server Groups and create a new server group.  Add all the servers you want to that group.

Highlight the group, then right-click for a new query window.

[image]

Any t-sql you run will be executed on all servers.  (If you want to test this, use `select @@servername`.)

So, your jobs.  When you make a change on one server, choose script -> drop and create to -> clipboard and paste it into a query window pointing at that group.  Edit the scripted job to replace "job_id" with "job_name" and the correct job name.

Clicking Execute will update the job on all servers in the group.

(I got this image from [this related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/save-connections-in-ssms) on DBA.stackexchange.  [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/14/sql-server-2008-ssms-feature-multi-server-queries/) is another useful link.)